# invoke and validate data

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to validate data, and depends on the result checked or unchecked the related check box, but getting below error?

***Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a03ee' 
Expected ')'***

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>

<%
Function Select()

Dim apple, banana, true
Dim SQL

SQL = " SELECT code, name, value FROM fruits WHERE code = '" &("myCode")& "'"


   If (SQL = SQL & "name <> '" banana "' AND value <> '" true "' ") or (SQL = SQL & "name = '" banana "' AND value <> '" true "' ")  Then

            checkedBox.Common.Name  = "chkbanana"
            checkedBox.Checked      = false     

        Else
            checkedBox.Common.Name  = "chkbanana"
            checkedBox.Checked      = true     
   End If

    If (SQL = SQL & "name <> '" apple "' AND value <> '" true "' ") or (SQL = SQL & "name = '" apple "' AND value <> '" true "' ")  Then

            checkedBox.Common.Name  = "chkapple"
            checkedBox.Checked      = false     

        Else
            checkedBox.Common.Name  = "chkapple"
            checkedBox.Checked      = true     
   End If

End Function   
%>
```

Comment: VB.NET or VBScript?  You have tagged both, but they are not the same thing.

Comment: I suspect, by the way, that the issue is that you need to use `Or` instead of `||`.

Comment: You should read up on vbscript syntax.  You are mixing " " for strings with assignment inside of ( ) expressions.  Not good.  The compiler does not know what you want.  Also, the standalone code (less ASP objects) can be validated with the MS debugger.  Or comment out vb script code until it compiles.  Put lines in one by one until you fix all your errors.

Comment: I did notice that also Steve.  But what is the logical value of an assignment?  Not good coding practices.

Comment: @StevenDoggart, it is VBScript and i used or but still same error comes

Comment: There are so many errors on this piece of code, I don't know where to start. Do you even execute the SQL? It won't magically resolve those values for you. And what about the `banana` and `apple` variables? I think you want a variable called `fruitname` and set the value to the appropriate name. Also using a variable with the name `true` will throw you a compilation error eventually. And then there is the strange logic where you test on a unequal to `name` and unequal to `true` (we call that `false` btw) _or_ equal to `name` and unequal to `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of syntax errors. When concatenating strings you need to use `&` around `banana` and such. Also, the logic seems off as you are comparing something with itself and concatenating, basically you can get it to compile and never have it run any of your conditionals as the else statements will always be run. You may want to use `contains` or some other comparison.

But for syntax your first if statement should look like this:

```
If (SQL = SQL & "name <> '" & banana & "' AND value <> '" & true & "' ") Or (SQL = SQL & "name = '" & banana & "' AND value <> '" & true & "' ") Then
```

Also you should not use `true` as the name of a variable.